# Lenovo x1 gen9 @ ubuntu22 - touchpad too sensitive to touch

Tags: ubuntu, touchpad

I have a Lenovo X1 gen9 with Ubuntu 22 on it. The touchpad is too sensitive, often drags things around when i am moving the cursor, registering false clicks and double clicks. I found that the solution would be to use the xinput but i couldn't find what i have to change.

This is my `xinput list-props <device id>` output:

```
Device 'SYNA8009:00 06CB:CE57 Touchpad':
    Device Enabled (189):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (191): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000Synaptics-Touchpad (xorg-xserver) tap sensitivity too high
    libinput Tapping Enabled (346): 1
    libinput Tapping Enabled Default (347): 0
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (348):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (349):    1
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (350):       0
    libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (351):       0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Enabled (352):  1, 0
    libinput Tapping Button Mapping Default (353):  1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (325):       0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (326):       0
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (354):    1
    libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (355):    1
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (327):        1, 1, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (328):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (329):   1, 0, 0
    libinput Click Methods Available (356): 1, 1
    libinput Click Method Enabled (357):    1, 0
    libinput Click Method Enabled Default (358):    1, 0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (359):        0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (360):        0
    libinput Accel Speed (334):     0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (335):     0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (336):        1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (337):   1, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (338):   1, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (339):     0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (340):     0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (310):     1, 1
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (311):        0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (312):        0, 0
    Device Node (313):      "/dev/input/event10"
    Device Product ID (314):        1739, 52823Synaptics-Touchpad (xorg-xserver) tap sensitivity too high
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (341):       <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (342):       1
    libinput Scrolling Pixel Distance (343):        15
    libinput Scrolling Pixel Distance Default (344):        15
    libinput High Resolution Wheel Scroll Enabled (345):    1
```

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in the terminal to find the ID number of your touchpad

```
xinput --list
```

from example mine is 12

> DELL097D:00 04F3:311C Touchpad            id=**12**   [slave  pointer  (2)]

then set the scrolling speed with (change the 12 with your ID number for the touchpad)

```
input --set-prop **12** "libinput Scrolling Pixel Distance" 50
```

NB *higher* numbers make the scrolling *slower*

I don't know how to change the Default…
There is a way to have this saved with xorg conf file, but I don't know how… maybe someone can add/edit this answer